# Encrypt with node and Decrypt with Java

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, des

I use DES to encrypt a String parameter in nodeJs, but how do i use DES decrypt  that properly in Java.

In nodejs I use this method to encrypt: https://github.com/ElmerZhang/ezcrypto/blob/master/lib/des.js

```
var DES = C.DES = {
_blockSize : 2,

_keyschedule : null,

_state : new State(),

_init : function(k) {
    this._keyschedule = new KeySchedule(k);
},

encrypt : function(message, password, options) {

    options = options || {};

    // Determine mode
    var mode = options.mode || new C.mode.OFB;

    // Allow mode to override options
    if (mode.fixOptions)
        mode.fixOptions(options);

    var
    // Convert to bytes if message is a string
    m = (message.constructor == String ? UTF8.stringToBytes(message)
            : message),

    // Generate random IV
    iv = options.iv || util.randomBytes(8),

    // Generate key
    k = (password.constructor == String ?
    // Derive key from passphrase
    C.PBKDF2(password, iv, 8, {
        asBytes : true
    }) :
    // else, assume byte array representing cryptographic key
    password);

    // Create key schedule
    this._keyschedule = new KeySchedule(k);

    // Encrypt
    mode.encrypt(DES, m, iv);

    // Return ciphertext
    m = options.iv ? m : iv.concat(m);
    return (options && options.asBytes) ? m : util.bytesToBase64(m);
},

_encryptBlock : function(message, offset) {
    this._state.initialPerm(message, offset);
    for ( var i = 0; i <= 15; i++) {
        this._state.round(this._keyschedule.getKey(i));
    }
    this._state.finalPerm(message, offset);
}

};
```

and  this is my des decrypt in java:

```
public class DES {

  private static byte[] iv = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

  public static String encryptDES(String encryptString, String encryptKey) throws Exception {
    IvParameterSpec zeroIv = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(encryptKey.getBytes(), "DES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key, zeroIv);
    byte[] encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(encryptString.getBytes());

    return Base64.encode(encryptedData);
  }

  public static String decryptDES(String decryptString, String decryptKey) throws Exception {
    byte[] byteMi = new Base64().decode(decryptString);
    IvParameterSpec zeroIv = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(decryptKey.getBytes(), "DES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, zeroIv);
    byte decryptedData[] = cipher.doFinal(byteMi);

    return new String(decryptedData);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why DES? It's old and busted (read: broken).

Comment: just a problem in this,asking for help

Comment: Well, it uses DES in OFB mode, possibly using PBKDF and possibly some encodings. What have you tried? If you don't post Java code then this question is going to be closed.

Comment: here is my DES decrypt in JAVA

Comment: Please explain, in as much detail as possible, why this Java code doesn't appear to work.

Comment: in node,i use DES encrypt a String and send this encrypted string to Android, in android,use this java code to decrypt receive String ,but cannot decrypt it correctly